# A set of SWRL rules from practice or research

Tags: owl, semantic-web, swrl

Altough a lot of theoretical work and frameworks exist I have not found an exemplary SWRL rule repository (from a research project,...). I googled a lot and found single SWLR rules but not a whole set of rules which can be used for a certain domian; In other words: I am looking for a "[pizza.owl](https://github.com/owlcs/pizza-ontology/blob/master/pizza.owl)" for SWRL...

Do you know a research project where such a set of SWRL rules was published?
Thanks

Comment: There was the "family.swrl.owl" file in TopBraid Composer examples, at least in old distributions. Possibly this file is the same: http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/examples/family.swrl.owl